# trying to find out places located within list

Tags: python, list

For example I am looking for a way to search every spot in a list to see where an object is located.  Some example psuedocode could go:

```
for every column in current row:
  if column is the first one:
                  do this
  if column in the last one:
                  do that
  else:
     find the previous row and columns place
```

Basically I am at a standstill so any insight would be helpful thanks

EDIT Sample Code:

```
for row in range(0,h+1):
      newrow=[]
      if row==0:
           newrow=[1]
      elif row==1:
           newrow=[1,1]
      else:
          for column,x in enumerate(row):
              if column==0:
                  newrow.append(1)
              elif column==len(row)-1:
                  newrow.append(1)
              else:
                  newrow.append(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `list.index`?

```
l = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
i = l.index('bar')
# i is 1, because l[1] == 'bar'
```

If you need special handling based on whether it's the first or last item:

```
# using i from above
if i == 0:
    # it's the first item
elif i == len(l) - 1:
    # it's the last item
else:
    # it's neither first nor last
```

Or if you need to process all items anyway, consider using `enumerate` to keep track of indices throughout the loop:

```
for i, x in enumerate(mylist):
    if i == 0:
        # x is the first item
    elif i == len(mylist)-1:
        # x is the last item
    else:
        # x is in the middle
```

Comment: thank you for the help.  i edited my code to show the work i currently have but there is a breakdown after the first else, my eyes have been staring at it for so long that I hope some fresh eyes can help me realize my mistake.  Thanks again tho!

Answer (score 1):

bardockyo:

The problem appears to be that you don't have a list in row... when you run the code 'for row in range(0,h+1):', row will always be an integer with a value between greater than or equal to 0, and less than or equal to h.

Are you trying to read a file a row at a time, and keep track of the row numbers?  If so, you should use a separate counter to track the row number...

I can't quite follow what you're trying to accomplish, so I can't even generate code to help you...

Added in response to bardockyo's comment:

I believe this accomplishes your goal:

```
# Setting h to a value so that I can use your 'range' line.
h = 5

# Create a blank dictionary object to store the row data.
rows = {}

for row_number in range(0,h+1):
    row_data = []
    # range isn't inclusive of the end value by default, to 'make it work', we
    # must add 1 to the row_number.
    for val in range(0,row_number+1):
        if val == 0 or val == row_number:
            # Determine if the value in 'val' is either the first number or
            # last number in this row, and if so append '1' to the list.
            row_data.append(1)
        else:
            # Determine if the value in 'val' is not the first number or last
            # number in this row, and if so append '2' to the list.
            row_data.append(2)
    # Store the row data in the row dictionary, with the key of 'row_number'.
    rows[row_number] = row_data

# Iterate through the dictionary.  There's no guarantee as to the order
# returned by the 'keys()' function, so I use sorted() to ensure it's in
# numerical order.
for row_num in sorted(rows.keys()):
    print 'Row Number %d contains the list:' % row_num,
    for val in rows[row_num]:
        print '%d' % val,
    print ''

# There are better (read: cleaner) ways to format the output for printing,
# but they can be hard to read.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! but yes i am trying to find out what row it is and ill outline what I wish my result to be also. basically I am need if it is the 1st row print [1] if it is the second row print [1,1] so basically row 1 should have one column while row 5 would have 5.. the else factor that I am trying to find is for the first column in say row 3 print a 1 and the last column in that row print a 1, while filling in a 2 in all the available spots like so:  [1] then [1,1] then [1,2,1] then [1,2,2,1] etc.  sorry i know it is confusing, i am fairly new at python